# Nested group in mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation

I'm using Mongo DB and I have a list of object that I need to group in category -> subcategory -> different types of subcategory grouped together.
You can find the code in this mongodb playground > https://mongoplayground.net/p/BfR7FT28XKN

I create the group category -> all the sub category.
But how can I group the subcategory with the same name?

My goal is to achieve something like that:

```
{
    "_id": "Food and Drink",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "details": "Wine Bar",
        "subCategory": "Bar",
      },
      {
        "details": "Jazz and Blues Cafe",
        "subCategory": "Nightlife",
      },
      {
        "subCategory": "Restaurants",
        "types": [
              {
                "details": "Mediterranean",
                "subCategory": "Restaurants",
              },
              {
                "details": "Mexican",
                "subCategory": "Restaurants",
              }
           ]
       },
      
    ]
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your out come is still unclear to me. Why other documents don't have types array. And why the one with types array have no details but it is nested in documents inside array.

Comment: The example above is a simplification to explain what I want: if you run the query in the mongodb playground you'll see all the categories grouped with all the subcategories inside..but you'll find subcategory with the same name like "Restaurants"..I want also them to be grouped in a array that I call "types". The array "types" must be created only if there are more than one subcategory with the same name..hope I explain myself

Comment: I suggest that you keep your interface consistent, keep the types array if there is no document keep it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need. You need to group by both category and sub category first. I have pushed complete document in types. You can filter the fields or do changes as per your requirements.

```
[{
"$match": {
  "category": {
    "$ne": null
  },
  "subCategory": {
    "$ne": null
  }
 }
},
{
 $group: {
  _id: {
    cat: "$category",
    sub: "$subCategory",
    
   },
   docs: {
    $push: "$$ROOT"
   }
 }
},
{
$group: {
  _id: "$_id.cat",
  subCategories: {
    $push: {
      subCategory: "$_id.sub",
      types: "$docs"
    }
  }
 }
}]
```

Remove `types: "$docs"` from last stage and this is what you'd get

```
[{
"_id": "Community",
"subCategories": [
  {
    "subCategory": "Education"
  },
  {
    "subCategory": "Disabled Persons Services"
  }
 ]
},
{
 "_id": "Food and Drink",
 "subCategories": [
  {
    "subCategory": "Bar"
  },
  {
    "subCategory": "Nightlife"
  },
  {
    "subCategory": "Restaurants"
  }
 ]
}]
```

Playground
https://mongoplayground.net/p/nwyAivJOZj5

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need